# Customizing Filters in ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm fairly new to Dynamic Data Entities, and I have couple questions about filters if you could help.

I want to create dynamic search pages that can work for different tables, so I used the **QueryableFilterRepeater control**
you know its implemented by adding some meta data to the table/class:

```
[FilterUIHint("Filter-Type")]
public Column City { get; set; }
```

the filters I add appears at the top of the table's aspx page, ***A. is it possible to display the filters on a different page or even a pop up window, and when the filters are applied (an OK Button i guess) the result would appear on the original page ?***

I tried using the **Modal Popup Extender** but I also failed, something like:

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                BackgroundCssClass="Background"
                PopupControlID="FilterRepeater"
                TargetControlID="btnFilter"
                CancelControlID="btnClose"
                OkControlID="btnOk">
            </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

The **ToolkitScriptManager** contradicted with the **DynamicDataManager**

My second question :

B. **is it possible to add multiple filters to the same column** using the **[FilterUIHint("Filter-Type")]** meta data ?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so i just added a panel around my filter, and assigned that panel to the modal and all worked i got my filters as a pop up window  .